# React Native IOS: ignore swipe

Tags: react-native, gestures

У меня есть `TouchableOpacity` на весь экран, и соответственно метод его `onPress`. Метод обрабатывает GestureResponderEvent, и в зависимости от `nativeEvent.locationX`, решает переключать вправо или влево контент. 
Тут есть проблема со свайпами: в какой части экрана (в правой или в левой) отпустить свайп, то он воспримет как одиночное нажатие на эту часть. Т.е. происходит ложное срабатывание. 
Вопрос: как сделать чтобы свайп справа-налево/слева-направо не обрабатывался как `onPress` ?

Answer (score 0):

Использование `TouchableOpacity` для такого кейса мне кажется неправильным.

Можно использовать эту библиотеку: `react-native-swipe-gestures`, если уже используется `react-native-reanimated`, то использовать `PanGestureHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

1. добавил метод на onPressIn который сохраняет координату Х.
2. в сам метод onPress добавил сравнение текущей координаты Х, и сохранённой Х от метода onPressIn. Если не равны то это свайп и игнорим, т.е. return;